# Logging debug statements from multiple requests in parallel using log4net

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, log4net, error-logging

I need to write log statements for debugging in an Asp.Net WebService. I have used log4net for that.

If I am having 8 requests in parallel executing on IIS, the log statements will get mixed with each other. I need to have the statements from one Request written collectively and then the other Request.

Can I do this using log4net. If not, can someone suggest any other approach for doing this?

Can I have an XML file with one node for each of the Request and then debug statements going to that node for a particular Request.

Comment: use mutex to synchronize it - but you lose the parallel execution.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution for this. We can keep on logging into memory (e.g. StringBuilder) and then at the end of the Request, write that collective statements into log at once.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    HttpContext.Current.Items["DebugLog"] = sb;
    Logger.LogMemory("Timestamp::" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"));
}

protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Logger.Log(((StringBuilder)HttpContext.Current.Items["DebugLog"]).ToString());
}

class Logger
{
    public static void Log(string message)
    {
        //Log here
    }

    public static void LogMemory(string message)
    {
        ((StringBuilder)HttpContext.Current.Items["DebugLog"]).Append(message);
    }
}

class A: Logger
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        LogMemory("some message for logging");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to dispatch logs depending on thread id: if you use a text logger you cannot group log elements when writing to the log. Here are some possibilities to sidestep this problem:

- Log to a single log file and query the log file by regrouping entries according to thread id using a tool like [LogParser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logparser). This lets you keep the raw view to the log yet create reports on it.
- Log to a database using a [AdoNetAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender.html) and query the DB grouping on thread ids. It is a viable solution but I very much prefer the first one since you lose the simple access on the logs.
- Name all your threads then in the configuration create as many appenders as there are threads; using a `PropertyFilter` dispatch only log one thread per appender